# Python PWD Module for Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, linux, system-administration

Does anyone know if this exists? If not, does anyone know why?

python's pwd module - https://docs.python.org/2/library/pwd.html

Answer (score 2):

The `getpw*` methods in [Etc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/etc/rdoc/Etc.html) look pretty similar.

Comment: Your right, that's what I was looking for. Thanks!